# Appointment booking

Tags: php, html, css

We have an instrument which around 100 students will be using. 
The plan is to have online slot booking, where each student can book a slot 
depending on their convenience.

Now the requirements are

1. Students can book the pre-defined slots.
2. Students can edit **ONLY** their slots, like cancel the appointment, etc.

The first requirement is fulfilled by many web based applications like Google Calendar.
**The important issue is the 2nd requirement**, which is an absolute necessity since, we don't have one person to handle rescheduling or cancelling for such a large number of students.

I have a working knowledge of HTML and CSS (I have created a website for private use, nothing fancy!). And I learned PHP and created a website with user login system. Now the next task is to add the slot booking functionality.

Let's say I need the following functionality in slot booking:

1. 4 slots everyday between 2:00 PM to 4:00 PM.
2. slots can be booked only one month in advance.
3. Only unbooked slots are visible to book when student login to their account.
4. Everyone can **see** who has booked the slot on which day.

Now, **what would be the best/simplest/easiest way to do it**?
I am open to learning new web languages if that is the only way.

Comment: And the question is? :) I guess it's _I don't know how to do this_?

Comment: @dbf I am sorry forgot to mention the main part... yes the question is I don't know how to do this.. I edited the post..Thank You

Comment: *i dont know how to do this* is not a question!

Comment: @Hemant - Please read my answer and do some research on it. Ask specific questions about SQL, not broad ones like this. You're specifically going to want to know about INSERT, DROP, and UPDATE for SQL, and a few other tidbits.

Comment: @Dagon I understand Your point. But The reason I ask is that i am not from a web development background. And I understand that I should not waste anyone's precious time by asking vague question. I am just looking for a best possible direction to look/ since this thing is kind of overload for me.
--@.Revolt Thank you very much I will look into it and get back to you if I have doubts. I made the php login website with xml database I started with SQL but it appeared daunting. Guess I have to face the deamon.. Thank You again!!

Comment: looks like you best option would then be to hire someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be pretty easily done using SQL queries. Have a MySQL table for your appointments in the same database as your users. Manually add some appointments at some select times, and then in the user system allow the user to see the available appointments, and then register for one (change a row on the appointment for userid or something to their id). With this, they can delete appointments, or edit them, where their id = registered userid.

You can run SQL queries to show who has which appointments as well.

Basically, just do a bit of research on SQL. I don't want to go too in-depth because I'm here to assist, not to do everything for you. If you have specific questions, don't be afraid to post them.

You're specifically going to want to know about INSERT, DROP, and UPDATE for SQL, and a few other tidbits. Google is your friend to find some nice tutorials.

Comment: Thank You I will get back to you !!

Comment: Thanks Revolt !!! I made the website and it's up and running. Thanks for the tip...